# Linearity of residue function from the derivative definition

Tags: analysis

Let $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be diferentiable in $U$ (open set), let $a \in U$ such that $[a,a+h] \in U$. We know that by definition

$$f(a+h) - f(a) = f'(a)(h) + r(h)$$ i want to prove that $r$ is a linear function fitst i assum $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $[a,a+v] \in U$ and

$$f(a+v) - f(a) = f'(a)(v) + r(v)$$

we know that $r(h) \rightarrow 0$ when $h \rightarrow 0$ and $r(v) \rightarrow 0$ when $v \rightarrow 0$ but i got stuck to prove that $r(v) + r(h) \rightarrow 0$ when $(h+v) \rightarrow 0$. Cause if this hapens we can assume $r(v+h) = r(v)+r(h)$.

Comment: This is false by a mile; it would imply that $f(a+h) - f(a)$ is linear in $h$ for any differentiable function.

Comment: let $g_{a}(v) = f(a+v) - f(a)$, so $g_{a}(h) + g_{a}(v) = f'(a)(v+h) + r(h) + r(v)$ the full exercise is to prove that $g_{a}$ is a linear function, so if $r$ isn't linear then the exercise is impossible?

Comment: Take $a=0, f(x)=x^2.$ In this case $r(h) = h^2.$